# schedule the execution of a function

Tags: javascript

I have a simple addition function, it is working fine. But what I want is, the addition function want to execute after five seconds. How can I achieve this task with setTimeout.

Here is the addition function

```
function fun(a,b) {
  return (a+b)
}

fun(1,1)
```

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: I tried but I am getting errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function fun(a, b) {
  return a + b
}

setTimeout(() => console.log(fun(1, 1)), 5000);
```

If you have a multiline function to execute:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  fun(1, 1);
  fun(3, 4)
}, 5000);
```

Since your requirement is a delay of *five seconds* and not *five thousand miliseconds*, you can improve the readability by specifying the number of seconds and then multiplying it by 1000:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  fun(1, 1);
}, 5 * 1000);
```

**Don't forget that `setTimeout` is asynchronous, so any lines of code following `fun(1, 1)` will eventually be executed prior to `fun`**

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(() => {
  fun(1, 1)
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function fun(a,b) {
  return (a+b)
}

setTimeout(fun(1,1), 5000);
```